# WPF Static Background Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, static, background-image

How do you get a static background image in WPF.  With an image set using the `imagebrush` it always expands or contracts when I resize or extend my window.  How do I make the image static so when I extend a window more of the image is revealed and not resized?  ie - similar to web design css or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ImageBrush property `Stretch` to `None` (default is `Fill`).

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="None" Source="src"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Might also need to anchor it to a corner (probably top left) using AlignmentY & AlignmentX.

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="None" 
                Source="src"
                Viewbox="0.25, 0.25, 1, 1"
                AlignmentY="Top"
                AlignmentX="Left"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Comment: Nope, background still moves when window is resized.

Comment: Got it.  you have to anchor it to a corner (probably the top left) using Alignment and then you can use Viewbox to adjust the image.  Added to answer.